# Get SOAP message from Wildfly WebServiceContext

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wildfly

I have a Wildfly 8.1.0 WebService with 4 WebMethods.

I need to log SOAP message (business requirement)

I injected the WebServiceContext which works

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext wsContext;
```

I can get the **org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WrappedMessageContext**:

```
WrappedMessageContext wrappedMessageContext = (WrappedMessageContext) wsContext.getMessageContext();
```

and also the **org.apache.cxf.message.Message**:

```
Message message = wrappedMessageContext.getWrappedMessage();
```

But not the SOAP message.

Anyone has some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately injecting the WebServiceContext and trying to get the SoapMessage did not work, so I went the SOAPHandler way.

Added a handler chain to my web service:

```
@HandlerChain(file = "my-handler.xml", name = "MyWebServiceHandler")
```

Created my own handler class and implemented javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler.

From my SOAPHandler implemented method "handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context)" I could get hold of the SOAP message like this:

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage = context.getMessage();
soapMessage.writeTo(outputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're retrieving the wrong/unnecessary message context. What you should have is the [`SOAPMessageContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPMessageContext.html), from which you can easily get the `SOAPMessage`. You should have instead:

```
SOAPMessageContext msgCtxt = (SOAPMessageContext) wsContext.getMessageContext();
       SOAPMessage soapMsg = msgCtxt.getMessage(); //gotten your SOAP message
       //log your message
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, it appears you're injecting a CXF-specific `MessageContext` (probably shouldn't do that, for the sake of obvious portability problems).

```
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage soapMessage =  (org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage)wrappedMessage.getWrappedMessage();     //continuing from your current code
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WrappedMessageContext cannot be cast to javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext

Comment: See my edit @javapenguin. I don't recommend continuing down your current route, as your code will not portable/easy to deal with

Comment: I'm not the one injecting the CXF-specific MessageContext. That is wildfly's doing.